# QueryDSL intersection with Spring Boot Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am using QueryDSL within a Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA project. 
I have the following schema for a table called `test`:

```
| id | key  | value |
|----|------|-------|
| 1  | test | hello |
| 1  | test | world |
| 2  | test | hello |
| 2  | foo  | bar   |
| 3  | test | hello |
| 3  | test | world |
```

Now I want to write the following SQL in QueryDSL:

```sql
select id from test where key = 'test' and value = 'hello'
INTERSECT
select id from test where key = 'test' and value = 'world'
```

Which would give me all ids where key is 'test' and values are 'hello' and 'world'.

I did not find any way of declaring this kind of SQL in QueryDSL yet. I am able to write the two select statements but then I am stuck at combining them with an `INTERSECT`.

```java
JPAQueryFactory queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(em); // em is an EntityManager

QTestEntity qTestEntity = QTestEntity.testEntity;

var q1 = queryFactory.query().from(qTestEntity).select(qTestEntity.id).where(qTestEntity.key("test").and(qTestEntity.value.eq("hello")));
var q2 = queryFactory.query().from(qTestEntity).select(qTestEntity.id).where(qTestEntity.key("test").and(qTestEntity.value.eq("world")));;
```

In the end I want to retrieve a list of ids which match the given query. In general the amount of intersects can be something around 20 or 30, depending on the number of key/value-pairs I want to search for.

Does anyone know a way how to do something like this with QueryDSL ?

EDIT:

Assume the following schema now, with two tables: `test` and 'user':

```
test:

| userId  | key  | value |
|---------|------|-------|
| 1       | test | hello |
| 1       | test | world |
| 2       | test | hello |
| 2       | foo  | bar   |
| 3       | test | hello |
| 3       | test | world |

user:

| id | name     |
|----|----------|
| 1  | John     |
| 2  | Anna     |
| 3  | Felicita |
```

The correspond java classes look like this. `TestEntity` has a composite key consisting of all of its properties.

```java
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    private String pubmedId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "value", nullable = false)
    private String value;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "key", nullable = false)
    private String key;
}

@Entity
class User {
  @Id 
  private int id;

  private String name;

  @ElementCollection
  private Set<TestEntity> keyValues;
}
```

How can I map the `test` table to the `keyValues` properties within the `User` class?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I'd probably just use an `OR` expression:

```
queryFactory
    .query()
    .from(qTestEntity) .select(qTestEntity.id)
    .where(qTestEntity.key("test").and(
        qTestEntity.value.eq("hello")
       .or(qTestEntity.value.eq("world")));
```

However, you specifically mention wanting to use a set operation. I by the way think you want to perform an `UNION` operation instead of an `INSERSECT` operation, because the latter one would be empty with the example given.

JPA doesn't support set operations such as defined in ANSI SQL. However, Blaze-Persistence is an extension that integrates with most JPA implementations and does extend JPQL with set operations. I have recently written a QueryDSL extension for Blaze-Persistence. Using that extension, you can do:

```
List<Document> documents = new BlazeJPAQuery<Document>(entityManager, cbf)
    .union(
         select(document).from(document).where(document.id.eq(41L)),
         select(document).from(document).where(document.id.eq(42L))
    ).fetch();
```

For more information about the integration and how to set it up, the documentation is available at https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/index.html#querydsl-integration

Answer (score 0):

Your TestEntity is not really an Entity, since it's id is not a primary key, it's the foreign key to the user table.

If it's only identifiable by using all its properties, it's an @Embeddable, and doesn't have any @Id properties.

You can map a collection of Embeddables as an @ElementCollection part of another entity which has the id as primary key. The id column in your case is not a property of the Embeddable, it's just the foreign key to the main table, so you map it as a @JoinColumn:

```
@Embeddable
public class TestEmbeddable {

    @Column(name = "value", nullable = false)
    private String value;

    @Column(name = "key", nullable = false)
    private String key;
}

@Entity
class User {
  @Id 
  private int id;
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
     name="test",
     joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id")
  )
  private Set<TestEmbeddable> keyValues;
}
```

In this case, the QueryDSL becomes something like this (don't know the exact api):

```
user.keyValues.any().in(new TestEmbeddable("test", "hello"))
  .and(user.keyValues.keyValues.any().in(new TestEmbeddable("test", "world"))
```

Comment: You are indeed correct. The QTestEntity is part of another entity. With your suggestion the QueryDSL does become much clearer. I am now struggling to find a way to map the `TestEntity` to the `Users` class. I made an edit to my original post. The issues I have is that the `TestEntity` has an composite key consisting of all of its properties, but I do only need to match the `userId` to the `id` of `user`. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: I updated the answer. I'm not sure if the QueryDSL works like that or you need to do something with .key("hello") and .value("world").